# Position of symbol of currency

Tags: output-formatting

When I use
`Quantity[45.51,"Euros"]`
the output is

> €45.51

I would wish to control if symbol € is on the right like 45.51 €
And also when I use `Quantity[13.10, "Euros"/"Months"]` the output is

> 13.10 €/months

```
we at least en Eu use €/month.
```

Can somehow decide through options this outputs ?

Comment: You can insert this symbol manually to where you wish from the Palettes => Special Characters

Comment: `$Post = (# /. {Quantity[q_, "Euros"] :> StringForm["\`\`€", q],
      Quantity[q_, "Euros"/"Months"] :> StringForm["\`\`€/month", q]
      }) &;`